# Regarding Leibniz formula for $\pi/4$ proof and its convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} & = \arctan(1)\;=\;\int_0^1 \frac 1{1+x^2} \, dx \\[8pt]
& = \int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\,x^{2n+2} }{1+x^2}\right) \, dx \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2} \, dx.
\end{align}

After this integration, $\frac{\pi}4\;=\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$

1.
I have trouble understanding why

$\int_0^1 \frac 1{1+x^2} dx  = \int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\,x^{2n+2} }{1+x^2}\right) dx$

2.
How to compare the convergence of

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$ and

$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\,x^{2n+2} }
{1+x^2}\right) dx$?

Which one converge faster and do not have the same range of convergence?

Answer (score 0):

Using long division, the integrand $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x^2}&=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots +(-1)^nx^{2n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kx^{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}
\end{align}$$

Thus, the integral of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kx^{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\int_0^1x^{2k}\,dx+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Since $\left|\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\right| \le\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converges, the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}=\pi/4$$

and we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.